# Apache Airflow Docker - How do I know which "Extras" are included

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

1. I tried to identify what Airflow "extras" has in Docker Image - [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/airflow/apache/airflow/1.10.14/images/sha256-f720c04cc5b5f21ec0949452c881104e9b277371b4cab43af5821593c5088523?context=explore)
2. I tried to read documentation [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/airflow) - but it tells me nothing about what's already included if I pull the Docker Image. It only says "These are the extras and install them from PIP". But I am already downloading Docker Image - so why do I need to install Airflow from PIP again?
3. I find this Dockerfile from a known tag 1.10.14 - but I interpreted it as

   a. Please install the packages from apt pkg manager

   b. Don't install it through PIP

I am struggling to answer "Do I have the extras e.g. LDAP in my downloaded 1.10.14 tag of Airflow, or not?"

Answer (score 0):

You will find list of default extras in the official documentation from the image (BTW. The image contains standard label with URL to that documentation):

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build-arg-ref.html#basic-arguments

Just scroll a bit and you will see the list.

Also the same documentation covers a lot of cases on how to extend the image or how to build your own custom image if needed (and all the other information)

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html

BTW. Airflow 1.10.* is End of Life for more than 8 months now, so you should not use it as it contains a lot of outdated packages and even security problems that will never be fixed.

Also the image might not build any more (and this will not be fixed if it does not).